# Sleep function in Capybara/Cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, capybara

I have a page on my site that I'm trying to test that requires that a user spend at least five seconds on the page before proceeding. Is there a way with Capybara to get my Cucumber tests to pause on that page and wait five seconds before proceeding with the next step I describe?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I have this in my step definitions:

```
Given /^I wait for (\d+) seconds?$/ do |n|
  sleep(n.to_i)
end
```

In your feature:

```
Given I am on the whatever page
And I wait for 5 seconds
And I follow "A Link"
# etc...
```

Comment: I would also suggest, in addition to the general sleep step, that sleeping be added to a specific step scoped to its purpose. For example: if the step was "Given I am on the waiting page", inside that step @blim8183 should sleep for 5 seconds. Then this more focused step could be used.

Comment: If you put this general sleep step in your steps file, you can then [call it from other steps](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Calling-Steps-from-Step-Definitions) with `step "I wait for 5 seconds"`. I use this to add slight delays into many other steps.

Answer (score 1):

It would be also great to define dynamically the time unit like this one :

```
Given /^I wait for (\d+) (second|minute|hour)s?$/ do |n, unit|
  sleep(eval("#{n.to_i}.#{unit}"))
end
```

Comment: Never use `eval`. You're only asking for trouble. `sleep(n.to_i.send(unit))`